# what is the function to print out typedoc in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

It looks like there are three types of documentation in Elixir (v1.1.1 is the version I am using now), `@doc`, `@moduledoc`, and `@typedoc`.

In `iex`, `@doc` and `@moduledoc` can be printed out by `h/1`, but not `@typedoc`. I know `t/1` can print out the type definition, but I need the documentation.

Any reason why `h/1` only supports `@doc` and `@moduledoc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet. We should update `IEx` to support it. I have opened an issue: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/3830

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a prompt response, José!